# Does light have an unending journey?

Tags: visible-light, universe

When we shine a torch in a room its light travels to the back of the room.

What happens to the light of a star ? I dont suppose we can say it continues to travel to the back of the universe as the universe has no back. Does the light continues its journey forever ? Or does it somehow end into black holes which might work as light sinks ?

Comment: If you consider the star to be a sphere emitting light in all directions equally, the light is attenuated as function of 1/r^2. So assuming light doesn't encounter anything while it is travelling, the power of light will be attenuated until it becomes negligible.

Comment: But then why are we getting light from stars that might have been emitted just after big bang. I assume that must be really far and their light must have been negligible. It has not been negligible till now and if it is being attenuated where is the energy going ? I certainly have less knowldege but I thought attenuation (energy loss) was due to proppgation in medium. And from what you say the light will just become non existent after travelling certain distance, sounds wrong to me

Comment: There is a very recent theory (a mere hundred years approximately) that states that light is emitted in quanta of energy.

Comment: Comment to the question (v1): Are you really asking if a photon is a stable elementary particle?

Comment: @ babou : I know that light is emitted as photons, but do they simply disappear after a really really long journey as was suggested by Gotaquestion. @ Qmechanic : no I am more interested in knowing what is happening to light which passes in between the stars and planets as it goes on and continues in empty space, what is its destiny if it has any destiny ?

Comment: @ Qmechanic : but it wont hurt to know whether it is stable or not, is it stable ?

Comment: That is another question. From classical wave perspective, the power is inversely proportional to r^2 because the power that is emitted from a point spreads on a sphere's surface, the larger the sphere surface becomes, the less the power becomes at a certain point on that sphere's surface. From photon perspective, the same argument is true but instead of speaking about power of  wave, we speak about number of photons passing. Photons are stable and keep traveling, but the light as we know it is a huge number of photons. Negligible light means low number of photons @rijulgupta

Comment: @ Gotaquestion : but my question is this only that what is going to happen to the photon that is wandering the empty space, will it just keep on going and going in a particular direction FOREVER ? a bit hard to digest

Comment: Also please keep in mind that I mentioned in my first comment "assuming light doesn't encounter anything while it is traveling" In reality it does which causes certain portion of photons to change their direction, after they travel in the new direction for a while they get reflected by another body and so on. Eventually they get scattered in continous reflections. That is how photons still exist from the past. Your main question was about propagation itself, that is why I assumed light doesn't encounter anything

Comment: Photons are stable. Theoretically as long as space exists the photon will keep traveling as long as it wasn't reflected by an obstacle in its way. But what happens to a single photon is one thing, and what happens to huge number of them (defined as light or EM wave) is something else. Your question suggests you are referring to light which attenuates because the photons making it diverge as they travel in space @rijulgupta

Comment: @Gotaquestion : so as you say light would start as lots of photons and end up being a single photon(other photons diverge) travelling in space into contnuum ?

Comment: Yes @rijulgupta assuming there are no reflections. When there are reflections photon meet each other again, not as bundle as they started, but as photons with crossing paths because one photon was reflected by body A while another was reflected by body B and so on

Comment: Well so lets say a photon has reached really really far away from the original position, so far that it has reached a point which is expanding away (hope I said it right) with more velocity than that of speed of light, now the velocity of this particular photon would be more than speed of light from point of observation. I do not know much but this seems incosistent with the established theory that speed of photons is equal to speed of light and is constant.

Comment: The speed of photon is the speed of light, no question about that. The expansion of space is one thing and the motion of a particle is a completely other thing. You can't consider the expansion of space as a velocity that is added to photon velocity. General relativity is the branch of physics that deals with those matters @rijulgupta

Comment: I hope you could care to explain why when we say that the speed of particles (expanding with speed > c)with respect to us is more than speed of light and hence when they emit their photons they cannot reach us because eveb when they go away from their source from our frame they are going back with their framd and hence not reaching us. Why wont a photon which has reached such a distance with respect to us have more speed ? Please do not say that it would never reach such a distance as we know that we would be receding from the photon as it would go away and this situation will come sometime

Comment: Your question is unclear to me. The maximum speed of a particle is c. Everybody agrees on that @rijulgupta

Comment: I was saying that when we say the universe is expanding with more speed than that of light, we say that 2 point on space with respect 2 each other are moving with speed mord than that of light, hence when our lonely photon reaches so much distance from us we would be moving with respect to each other with speed greater than speed of light and hence the photon would be moving with speed more than that of light with respect to us, now either our theories faik here or something must happen to the photon before something as such happens to it

Comment: We are not moving as in the classical description of motion, the space is expanding. Think of 2 points on balloons surface. When you inflate it, the points become more distant but they are not really moving, are they? The photon always travels at c. Accordingly, the photon you are speaking about will never make it to us because the increased distance is larger than the distance traveled by photon at certain time. All the photons we observe are within distances that photons can travel before distances become so great. @rijulgupta

Comment: @Gotaquestion : so you mean they do not have a speed with respect to one another, now that is definitely wrong ! And the photon I was talking about was never coming towards us but going away from us and the space it was at was also expanding taking us away from the point where the photon originated from as well. As I see now the concept of constant speed seems to be falling apart.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11223/discussion-between-rijul-gupta-and-gotaquestion)

Answer (score 1):

Light is emitted as photons. The inverse square law implies that the
density of photons decreases as the distance from the source
increases, exactly as it would if billiard ball were emitted in random
direction, rather than photons. The photons do not necessarily have
all the same energy. It depends on their wavelength. The energy of a
photon is not attenuated with distance (only the number of photons
is). However it is attenuated (red shifted) by spatial expansion of
the universe, while it is travelling, but that is a considerably
slower attenuation.

Now, if we were in a stable (non-expanding) infinite universe with
uniform average density, the question of the photon ultimately
encountering an obstacle would be similar to [Olbers'paradox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Olbers%27_paradox) (why does
the sky have dark patches rather than a shining star in all
directions?).  There would be an obstacle in all directions that the
photon would ultimately hit.  And since this question refers to the
future rather than the past as in Olbers' paradox, we cannot eliminate
the existence of this ubiquitous obstacle by relying on the young age
of the universe.

However, I think this inverse of Olbers' paradox can be dismissed with
an other argument relying on the expansion of the universe. Though the
universe may be infinite (I do not know), the reachable universe is
finite. The reachable universe has a radius such that the expansion at
the periphery has the speed of light with respect to the centre (it is
expansion, not motion), as made precise by the Hubble constant. The
reachable universe being finite, it may have direction where no
obstacle exist (depending on average matter density), and a photon
going (at light speed) in such a direction may go for ever.

This is only an approximation of an answer. Actual figures probably
matter, and there may be other phenomena.

Comment: So that would mean that our stars are just shooting energy right into nowhere ? Really nowhere ? Also I have a little bit of a confusion if 2 points on an expanding balloon (as many people talk of as expansion of universe analogue) are "expanding" away from each other would they not have a relative velocity ? Its like saying, yes they are going away from each other but no they are not moving

Comment: I did not say all photons will go for ever, but that some may. Last I
talked with them, stars did not seem very concerned with the ultimate
fate of their energy/particle output. Regarding the balloon view of
universe expansion, I have absolutely no expertise in cosmology. All I
understand is that space itself is expanding, like the surface of the
balloon. The distance between two points of space may increase, but
that does not count as mechanical motion within space. Your two points
are not moving with respect to the balloon surface.

Comment: But I do not care about the balloon surface, I am talking about the distance between the 2 points, man that is definitely changing and you can not deny it.

Comment: Your talk with stars must have been ablazed by the sparkling thoughts of the two parties in conservation. LOL :D

Comment: The distance between the two point is changing, certainly. But the two
points are not moving with respect to space (the ballon surface). In
our 3D space, I guess that means that two points at rest in the same inertial
frame do see their distance increase because of space
expansion. Actually I suspect it is a bit more subtle to state,
because I am not sure inertial frames still make as much sense at
scales that make expansion measurable. Ask someone with competence in
relativity, I am at the very end of my rope.

Comment: First of all the frames are non inertial and I am not trying to see from space as space is expanding, I am seeing from my point of reference, as I also expand with space, everything else moves away (the only possible way of expansion)

Answer (score 0):

Light beams are electromagnetic radiations, they stops when they meet some material that can stop them, in space generally they continue propagate until they have energy.

Comment: I know that @novalink , the question is what happens to light which does not fall on other planets etc.

Comment: If you cannot setup a measurement, in principle you can't say anything (that's physics, baby!). Anyway, since we have a very well working theory on that, called "electrodynamics", we can predict that it will travel on undisturbed as long as it doesn't hit matters. No interaction, no change.