# Variance in speed of light

Tags: general-relativity, speed-of-light, space-expansion, reference-frames, faster-than-light

While discussing this question ([Does light have an unending journey?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/82296/)) I stumbled on the fact that light's speed is constant only in inertial frame.

What I happened to do was add up the expansion of universe to the theory. It goes as follows:

Suppose from a source we emit a photon, at the same time, we (source) are moving away from the point of launch and so is the point that too with acceleration, now lets consider the moment when we are so far from the point of fire that the distance between the 2 points (source and firing point) is so much that the space with their respect to each other is moving with speed more than speed of light, certainly since the points are also constantly being separated they have a relative velocity of separation which just happens to be more than speed of light, now by the time the fired photon must have travelled even further and its speed now with respect to the source must be greater than speed of light.

Can this be taken as a prove for the variance of speed of light from inertial frames?

Answer (score 5):

You're assuming, incorrectly, that general relativity has a unique and natural way of describing the velocity of cosmologically distant objects. That isn't the case. There isn't any such definition, because velocity is a vector, and parallel transport of vectors is path-dependent.

Comment: But I am not transporting any vector, I am seeing the velocity of something while sitting in mh chair, I observe the space is expanding with more speee than distancd is increasing with more speed than c and hence speed with respect to me sitting in my chair is more than c

Comment: *I am seeing the velocity of something while sitting in mh chair...* One of the basic conceptual obstacles you need to get over in relativity is that idea that there is something going on "now," which you can determine by what you "see."

Comment: Then how are we going to make the observation ? Or should we not make the observation ?

Comment: You can, for example, make optical observations. But those optical observations do not tell you what is "really" happening "now" at some distant location.

Comment: Then what would those observations tell ? As far as I understand we would get the light from a star till it is at a point that the space between us and the star is expanding with speed less than that of light ; when the star has moved on even further its light will stop reaching us as the space would be expanding with more speed than speed of light. Similarly if the photon we fired reaches such a distance from our frame it would be moving away with speed more than c

Comment: @BenCrowell I always thought that parallel transport always by default happens along a geodesic, and there is always a unique shortest path between two points (in the sense of the induced locally euclidean metric). Closed spaces can include additional geodesics that pass through a pair of points, but there's a preferred one here.

Comment: @JanDvorak: *I always thought that parallel transport always by default happens along a geodesic...* Not sure what you mean when you say "by default." You can parallel transport a vector along any curve. Geodesics are special because they parallel transport their own tangent vectors.

Answer (score 0):

Current, standardized definition of *distance* is based on the assumption that speed of light is constant, inertial frame or not. (See, for instance, wikipedia's page on [metre](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metre)).

Nevertheless, *hypothesis* of variable speed of light [sometimes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_speed_of_light#Modern_VSL_theories_as_an_alternative_to_cosmic_inflation) is used in cosmology. Note, that this is *one of* possible explanations of observations and not the most widespread.

**Edit**. Upon reading OP's comments I would like to rephrase Ben Crowell's argument:
For curved spacetimes distance between two objects can grow at a rate exceeding the speed of light and that in no way violates general relativity and its postulate about the universality of speed of light. One way to understand this is to look at the space-time diagrams. Let's look at the one from [Ned Wright's Cosmology Tutorial](http://www.astro.ucla.edu/~wright/cosmo_02.htm)

[image: space-time diagram]

Small red triangles are the light-cones for given point -- that is if we draw space-time trajectory of an object at that point it will be inside the light-cone for that point, but the slant of the trajectory (which corresponds to the growth rate of distance) could be greater than the slant of the light-cone for *some other* point.

Comment: As I see your answer it seems like you are saying that it is a possible explanation, just a little thing your link has reference to speed greater than that of light for virtual photon at small distance, my theory is about actual photons that are highly separated from point of observation.

Comment: First, virtual photons traveling faster than light is definitely stretching the metaphor of virtual particles too far. The actual theories (quantum field theory) do not have FTL or VSL phenomena.

Comment: Second, my point is that cosmological observations do not **prove** variable speed of light, but could be interpreted with this concept. They can also be successfully interpreted without this concept.

Comment: Still what was your point ? Am I correct ?

Comment: My point is that your 'theory' is based on misunderstanding of cosmology, but the idea that speed of light is variable does have merit in the context of cosmology.

Comment: Ok, as far as my understanding goes is that the universe is expanding, cosmoly does not say that space is moving and neither am I, but I do say that for two points in space which see the universr at that distance expanding with speed more than speed of light, do so by seeing ( if it was possible) that the particular point is receding with such enormous speed, if we were to observe that the point was receding with just speed of light, why would we say that the universe was expanding with more speed ?

Comment: I could only repeat Ben Crowell argument that relative speed for objects separated by cosmological distances is badly defined concept. In particular, if we take derivative of some cosmological distance with respect to time the resulting quantity can exceed speed of light. But this does not constitute violation of the general relativity.

Comment: And why would that be so ? Please explain in laymans terms if possible, I am not specialised in these fields but if not possible I am ready to study the concepts to understand.

Comment: Look for instance at [this diagram](http://www.astro.ucla.edu/~wright/omega0.gif) (as well as the whole [tutorial](http://www.astro.ucla.edu/~wright/cosmo_02.htm)). Small triagles are the lightcones for a given point in the given coordinate frame. The distance between two points could grow faster than the speed of light, but because the spacetime is curved, and lightcones are 'deformed' relative to the lightcones at origin, this is compatible with given point on a slanted line being at rest locally.

Comment: I tried to completely understand it, but as far as I came to understand it wss that when we say universe expands for distances greater than certain distances with speed more than speed of light, we are using some new type of coordinates and in reality the universe is not expanding with speed more than speed of light, so is it correct that the universe does not expand with speed more than speed of light ?

Comment: That is the point! The answer to this question is reference frame dependent. If we take the frame comoving with matter in the universe, than yes, the universe expands at a rate exceeding speed of light.

Comment: I was so close to understanding it but you threw me into the dark abyss once more, Do you mean to say that we being matter in space and hence comoving with space can perceive light with more speed than that of light ?