# Does the strength of a beam of light determine how much distance it can travel?

Tags: electromagnetism, cosmology, speed-of-light, earth

If I point a light torch to a cloudless, crystal clear and an absolutely pristine sky, will the light beam exit the planet and travel forever in the vacuum of space? (assuming it doesn't get perturbed by anything)? Or alternatively, if I launch a single photon in the vacuum of space....will it keep traveling forever? (again, we're assuming that the photon does not get disturbed by anything).

Comment: The answer is Yes.

As with any kind of object, wave, particle etc., if not stopped by something, it will continue at constant speed forevermore.

Comment: See [Beer-Lambert law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beer%E2%80%93Lambert_law). Light drop intensity due to absorption exponentially. Other effects, e.g. scattering, drag photons away from "straight" line, so that still less light reaches target

Comment: Do keep in mind that a single photon is not likely to be noticed throughout most of the universe, and any "light beam" will diverge, making the "brightness" of the beam weaker with distance.

Comment: related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/82296/58382

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question think of how we get light from the far away galaxies. It is the same problem as you posed, though inversing the path of the light. Each photon that we get from a galaxy, travelled for billions of years (depending how far is the galaxy).

However, take in consideration that the further we look into the sky, we have knowledge about the more distant past, and beyond the visible horizon we have only hypotheses. Since you mention in your comment that you send a single photon, and you exclude any perturbation (I also understand, no absorption) the same is bound to happen with it. But since you use of the word ***forever***, as the photon would reach more and more distant regions in the space, it would have travelled a longer time. What will happen billions of years from now on needs predictions about the future of our universe.

Comment: Light from distant galaxies/quasars/supernovas are comprised of an immense number of photons, thus a higher luminous intensity. I mentioned above that what if I pointed a light torch in the sky that launched only one single weak photon, will it still travel forever in the vacuum of space?

Comment: Light from distant galaxies does involve an immense number of photons, and every single one of them that reached the earth travelled for billions of kilometres just fine. Your single photon will keep going until it interacts with something, and if there is nothing to interact with it will go on "forever".